# What is the probability that the larger of two independent uniform variables on $[0,1]$ is greater than $3/4$ if the smaller one is less than $1/4$?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution, geometric-probability

Two independent random variables are uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

> The question asks if the smaller of the two numbers is strictly less than 
>   $\frac{1}{4}$, then what is the probability that the larger one is strictly greater than $\frac{3}{4}$.

I approached the question with trying to find a suitable area within the unit square. I got two lines that cut off a smaller square of $\frac{1}{4}$ length, hence I calculated the probability as $\frac{1}{16}$; but the answer given is $\frac{2}{7}$ and now I can't understand where I'm wrong.

Comment: The set of pairs $(x,y) $ such that $\min(x,y) < {1 \over 4} $ is L shaped.

Comment: Note that both variables have to be independently distributed for you to reach an answer based on given information.

Comment: Yes, I realised that I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used excel to solve the problem :D basic conditional probability problem

Yellow is the requirement (Condition) and Red is the region satisfying the property

[image]